# How to resize RelativeLayout/LinearLayout and content inside those layers programmatically, based on screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an Android application, for very first time.I am coming from web environment, and i am not sure if i can transfer my skills over Android UI as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SignUpHolder"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Yeah"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/someTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_with_string_sign_up_with_facebook"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see

> android:layout_width="350dp"

layout_width is set hardcoded by 350dp.
By this, this LinearLayer is not touching the screen of the phone and  will be in every kind of mobile screen.

I am looking for a way to cut the width of this LinearLayer by 20-50dp, but do not be way to small so ImageView and TextView to be cutted off.

Is there a way to get the phone screen width, calculate it and set this Layer dynamically by some dp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to achieve what I think you want would be to combine a `match_parent` width with horizontal margins. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SignUpHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp">
```

This will cause your `LinearLayout` to be as wide as whatever parent it is inside of... minus `20dp` on each side.

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin. Instead of hard coding the width, use this in your linear layout tag

```
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```